# what does refer the word 'to' at the end of the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

What does refer the word 'to' at the end of the sentence?

1. This is the school which I used to go to.
2. This is the school which I used to go.

What's the difference between these two sentences, and which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

*This is the school which I used to go* is not a valid sentence. You don't *go school*, you *go to school.*

Some people don't like to end a sentence with a preposition so, to be very formal and correct, you could say *This is the school **to** which I used to go.*

Comment: "This is the school *where* I used **to go**." Isn't that grammatical?

Comment: Yes, of course, but not _which_.

Comment: But my main point being that you said "You don't go school" the OP doesn't say that in their question.

Comment: 'The school which I used to go' suggests that 'school' is the object of the verb 'go'.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting `to` at the end of the sentence makes the sentence hang. I guess it would help to dissect the sentence.

Think of the following as the base of the sentence:

> This is the school which I used to ....

In the simple past tense, `went to` is used.

> I went to this school.

In its simple present tense, `went to` would be `go to`. Append it to the "base" sentence, and you have:

> This is the school which I used to ... go to.

Take this sentence for comparison:

> This is the school I used to ... attend.

This might not be the most technical explanation, but I hope it helps.